# Can i include my session_functions.php in my header then call a function from body.php

Tags: php, session

My header.php looks like this.

```
include("sessions.php");
<h1>...
```

My sessions.php page looks like this

```
session_start();

function validate_user()
{
    //validate user
}
```

I have a user_class.php in my body. can i just call validate_user() because i have already included it in the page or do i have to include it in my user_class.php and every .php that uses a session function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes.  What your asking is essentially the whole purpose of includes.  Using includes you can divide you code into chunks (files) that represent functional units, such as your session handling.  As some of the other posters have suggested, one of your chunks might be your initialization code.

Imagine includes as simply inlining the file into the point of the include/require statement, replacing it.  In this model, as long as the function would appear above the point you are using it, you're good to go.

At the end of the day, it's you preference on how you divide up your code but books like the classic "Design Patterns" from the Gang of Four can help you make good decisions about how to design your code for maximum ease of maintenance and re-use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid mixing procedural code and function definitions.

Instead, move your procedural code (ie `session_start()`) to a separate file, eg `bootstrap.php` and include that at the top of your pages.

To ensure functions and classes defined in other files are included, use `require_once`. That way, you can safely include the required files without running into re-definition errors.

One more thing, `session_start()` should be called before anything is sent to the browser. Place it at the very top of your scripts for safety.

For example

#### bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// for development only
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
require_once 'functions.php';
```

---

#### functions.php

```
<?php
function validate_user()
{
    //validate user
}
```

---

#### header.php

```
<h1>...
```

---

#### user_class.php

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';

class User { ...
```

---

#### some_page.php

```
<?php
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'header.php' ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is good information but i guess my question is "Can i include my session.php filled with functions in my header then call one of those function from body.php" I think i can because it is all on the same page but something is not working out and i think that might be it.

Comment: @user1082764 Yes, including files imports them into the current namespace unless otherwise defined with a `namespace` declaration though it's better to be specific so use `include_once` / `require_once`. Also, check out my updated `bootstrap.php` above to enable error reporting while developing. I have a feeling it will shed light on any errors you may be running in to

Answer (score 0):

If your user_class.php relies on sessions.php having been included, you may want to put a `require_once "sessions.php";` at the top of your user_class.php. Additionally, I would recommend using `include_once` instead of just `include`.

Comment: this is a great suggestion and i will implement it immediately but doesn't quite answer my question.